# Hadoop HPROF profiling .profile location

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, profiling

I am testing out HPROF on Cloudera quick start VM but unable to find the .profile that is suppose to be generated. I am running the below:

```
hadoop jar ../lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar wordcount -Dmapreduce.task.profile=true -Dmapreduce.task.profile.params=-agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples,heap=sites,force=n,thread=y,verbose=n,file=%s -Dmapreduce.task.profile.maps=0-2 /user/cloudera/input /user/cloudera/output5
```

Any ideas on where I can find the file?

Thanks,